# Why some dynamic styles gets override but some don't in material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have four box component. I have applied styles for when the component is active and when it is being hovered.

Here is the code:

```
import styles from "./Menubar.module.css";

const Menubar = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState(null);

    const itemContainerStyles = {
        backgroundColor: "hsl(252, 69%, 76%)",
        color: "white !important",
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(252, 69%, 76%) !important",
        },
    };

    return (
        <Box>
            <Box className={styles.container}>
                <Box
                    className={styles.itemContainer}
                    sx={menu === "box1" ? itemContainerStyles : {}}
                    onClick={(event) => setMenu("box1")}
                >
                  Box1
                </Box>
                <Box
                    className={styles.itemContainer}
                    sx={menu === "box2" ? itemContainerStyles : {}}
                    onClick={(event) => setMenu("box2")}
                >
                  Box2
                </Box>
               <Box
                    className={styles.itemContainer}
                    sx={menu === "box3" ? itemContainerStyles : {}}
                    onClick={(event) => setMenu("box3")}
                >
                  Box3
                </Box>
                <Box
                    className={styles.itemContainer}
                    sx={menu === "box4" ? itemContainerStyles : {}}
                    onClick={(event) => setMenu("box4")}
                >
                  Box4
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default Menubar;
```

Here is the CSS module code:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 38px -10px rgba(22, 23, 24, 0.35), 0px 10px 20px -15px rgba(22, 23, 24, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 6px;
    width: 55px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.itemContainer {
    padding: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0px 4px;
    color: hsl(252, 69%, 56%);
}

.itemContainer:hover {
    background-color: hsl(252, 69%, 95%);
}
```

I wanted to achieve the functionality that If a box component is active then upon hover the color should not change to the hover color. Also, the active box should have a different colour.

So to achieve this I tried to override the styles, but in practice, the `background color` gets overridden but the `text color` and `hover color` do not so I had to use `!important` for those styles. I am confused about why the styles did not change even though they were inline styles.
Is there any other way to achieve this because using `!important` is not considered a good practice.

Comment: Have you tried ?
.itemContainer.active:hover {
 background: hsl(252, 69%, 76%);
}